# The given jQuery alert snippet is not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

This javascript alert is working:

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
      document.getElementById("tr_edit").innerHTML = "YOU CLICKED ME!";
    }
</script>
```

But this jQuery doesn't:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#tr_edit").click(function () {
            alert("The paragraph was clicked.");
        });
    });
</script>
```

I couldn't understand what i am missing. Please help.

Comment: Please remove the c# tag.

Comment: Make sure you link js library before your script tag`<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-4+XzXVhsDmqanXGHaHvgh1gMQKX40OUvDEBTu8JcmNs="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Comment: @Purushothaman it still doesn't work

Comment: Please add what you are trying to achieve as a snippet in your question

Answer (score 0):

It work, i think you have something wrong with your html

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#tr_edit").click(function () {
            alert("The paragraph was clicked.");
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" id="tr_edit">
```

Answer (score 0):

They're both working, but you never call `myFunction()`

For consistency and simplicity it would probably be better to stick with a solution in either jquery or plain javascript though.

```js
// All jquery
$("#tr_edit_jquery").click(function () {
    alert("Jquery was clicked.");
    $(this).text("YOU CLICKED ME!");
});

// All vanilla
const div = document.getElementById("tr_edit_js");
function jsFunction() {
  alert("Vanilla was clicked.");
  div.innerHTML = "YOU CLICKED ME!";
}

div.addEventListener("click", jsFunction);
```

```css
div {
  padding: .5rem;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    function myFunction() {
      document.getElementById("tr_edit").innerHTML = "YOU CLICKED ME!";
    }
    
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#tr_edit").click(function () {
            alert("The mixed implementation was clicked.");
            myFunction();
        });
    });
</script>

<div id='tr_edit'>click</div>

<div id='tr_edit_jquery'>jquery</div>

<div id='tr_edit_js'>vanilla</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but it still doesn't work

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. As you can see the three above snippets are working here. Perhaps you have made a mistake in declaring the classes of your elements in your HTML? Without more context I'm afraid I can't offer any other suggestions.